# how to use a onkeyup function in javaScript to get the value using ajax with spring

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, html

How to use the on key up event with timeout option. The values typed should return the data that matched in the data base
here my **Jquery code** is

```
function searchUserId() {
  var userId = $('#userId').val();
  //var moduleID = $('#moduleIdList').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "controlpanel/SearchUserData",
    type: "POST",
    data: "userId=" + userId,
      //+ "&roleName=" + roleName,
      //For Progress Bar                                    
    success: function(response) {
      alert(userId);
      $('#page-wrapper').html(response);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" tabindex="1" class="form-control" name="userId" id="userId" maxlength="20" 
   onkeyup="searchUserId();"data-validation-engine="validate[required]"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 'timeout option' I assume that you mean to use this to only trigger the function when the user has finished typing.

First you should remove the `onkeyup` attribute from the HTML.
Then add the following to your JS:

```
var timer;

$('#userId').on('keyup', function() {
  if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(searchUserId,300);
});
```

This will reset the timer if another keyup event is triggered within 300ms, so the function will not get triggered when the user is still typing. Of course you can set this to any value you like.

Comment: thankyou for your answer. here what is timer. what that variable holds?

Comment: @Amya the variable is set by `timer = setTimeout(searchUserId,300);`. By assigning `setTimeout()` to a variable we are able to reset it with `clearTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this
**HTML**

```
<input type="text" tabindex="1" class="form-control" name="userId" id="userId" maxlength="20" 
   "data-validation-engine="validate[required]"/>
```

**Jauery**

```
$('#userId').on('keyup',function () {
    var userId = $(thi).val();
    //var moduleID = $('#moduleIdList').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "controlpanel/SearchUserData",
        type: "POST",
        data: "userId=" + userId,
        //+ "&roleName=" + roleName,
        //For Progress Bar
        success: function(response) {
            alert(userId);
            $('#page-wrapper').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: working fine thanks for ur code.. i only misunderstood the code sorry!

Comment: @Amya its okay ,you are welcome and if your issue is solved then close your question by accepting my answer :)